# Header missing on one page (first page of section)

Tags: sectioning, scrartcl, header

A problem I am having is that I am missing a header on exactly one page throughout the 140 pages of my thesis and I can not figure out why. I am not using any packages like fancyhdr for headers - just `\pagestyle{headings}` at the beginning.
This is how it is supposed to look:
[image: How the heading should look]
My Latex file for this section looks like this:

```latex
\section{Einleitung}
\label{sec:einleitung}
\subsection{Motivation}
Raumakustik ist mitunter eines der wichtigsten Themen im Alltag,
dem allerdings in vielerlei Hinsicht nur sehr wenig Beachtung...
```

This works for every section except for one, where I get these results - with the header missing:
[image: My Problem]
But I still have the same code:

```latex
\section{Grundlagen der Raumakustik}
\label{sec:grundlagenRaumakustik}
Um gezielte Maßnahmen zur Verbesserung von Raumakustik umsetzen...
```

Is there anything I might have overlooked?
Thanks!

Comment: It is easy to change the page style or a header mark, but how should we know how you are doing it? Btw: your code can't create the picture, Akustik and Raumakustik are different words.

Answer (score 0):

I think your document looks like this.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside]{scrartcl}%I used \documentclass[10pt, a5paper, twoside]{scrartcl} in an effort to reduce time scrolling blank pages.
\usepackage[cp1251]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
%\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\pagestyle{headings}
\begin{document}%pdflatex
\section{alpha} Az.\newpage
\section{beta} Buki.\newpage
\section{gamma}\subsection{delta} Glagol'. Dobro.\newpage
Est'.\newpage\subsection{epsilon} Gis'n.
\end{document}
```

It appears to me that third section is the only section placed on an odd page (page 17). As you can see in my example first and third sections satisfy that 'odd' condition and miss headers on first pages.